# ftp not working

Tags: ftp

I was doing backup of my site, using filezilla, as I did for many years. it is a wordpress site with thousands of files and many folders. In the past it just did the backup with no problems. But now after some time, it says :

Response: 220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
Response: 220-You are user number 4 of 500 allowed.
Response: 220-Local time is now 08:46. Server port: 21.
Response: 220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
Response: 220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
Error: Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error: File transfer failed
Status: Connecting to ***(my server ip address here, which I deleted)***
Response: 220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
Response: 220-You are user number 5 of 500 allowed.
Response: 220-Local time is now 08:46. Server port: 21.

And this loop continues on and on, and installation does not progress, with many files remaining in the queue.

What is the problem? What must I do?

Comment: Questions about the usage of [software](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are really best asked over at [Super User](http://superuser.com/).